# How to convert a binary string to text string and the reverse in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, binary, type-conversion

What I wanna do is to input a string like `["01001000 01100101 01111001"]` and convert it to `["Hey"]` or the opposite too, input `["Hey"]` and convert it to `["01001000 01100101 01111001"]`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```dart
String encode(String value) {
  // Map each code unit from the given value to a base-2 representation of this
  // code unit, adding zeroes to the left until the string has length 8, and join
  // each code unit representation to a single string using spaces
  return value.codeUnits.map((v) => v.toRadixString(2).padLeft(8, '0')).join(" ");
}

String decode(String value) {
  // Split the given value on spaces, parse each base-2 representation string to
  // an integer and return a new string from the corresponding code units
  return String.fromCharCodes(value.split(" ").map((v) => int.parse(v, radix: 2)));
}

void main() {
  print(encode("Hey"));    // Output: 01001000 01100101 01111001
  print(decode("01001000 01100101 01111001"));    // Output: Hey
}
```

Comment: What about Decimal,Octal,Hex?the idea is to choose what to input and what to convert it to,so lets say I chose decimal so I know already its an int which is good and I want to convert the number 34 to binary , Octal,Hex,ASCII or vice versa how could i do that,btw thank you